# Consuming session variable in java from Asmx web service

Tags: c#, java, asmx

I have a asmx service in which i am maintaning  a session variable. We can consume that session variable from client code in c# by using

```
System.Net.CookieContainer CK = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```

is there anything equivalent to this in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by Java? Is it an applet, bean or something? What do you mean by client code? Do you want to call asmx web service from Java and pass a variable through the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie are just key value pairs in a header. In http request its `Cookie` and in http response its `Set-Cookie`

Check this [link](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html)